# connect sparkR with redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, sparkr

I have a question: Does anyone know how to connect sparkR with Redshift?

I am trying to use spark on my redshift cluster to do some querying and data wrangling

Thank you

Comment: from what i'm understand you want to download data from redshift to R?

Comment: yup, that's something i want to do: write a query and get the R's dataframe. I know how to do it conventionally ( using RPostgreSQL or RJDBC packages). I'm just wondering if I could the same thing with the sparkR package

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to do that, I'm using databricks for my spark cluster, I couldn't do it conventionally but something that work for me is that I first load the data in the SQLContext with Scala after that I can access with sparkR to the SQLContext, maybe it's not the best solution but it's working with a nice perfomance.

This is the conector [Link](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift)

In Scala I do this:

```
val redshift_data  = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")  
  .option("url", "jdbc://....")
  .option("tempdir", "s3a://....")
  .option("query", "SELECT * FROM table_name")
  .load()
  .registerTempTable("redshift_data")
```

Then in R

```
data <- sql(sqlContext, "SELECT * FROM redshift_data")
```

I really hope this may be helpful.